# WPF Dependency Property Based on another dependency property

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

Say I have a Control that has a Text Dependency Property.

```
        public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(Text), typeof(string), typeof(Enhanced_TextBlock), new PropertyMetadata(0));
```

How do I create another dependency property "CharacterCount" that would return length of Text Property while also being Dependency property?

Comment: The getter of that property has to be the Length of the Text property

Comment: Why should it be a dependency property, and not just an ordinary (and obviously read-only) CLR property? If you want to use it as the source of a Binding, just write `{Binding Text.Length}`.

Comment: @Clemens, DP can be used in Triggers natively

Comment: @ASh Sure, but is that what OP wants to do?